# Trying to produce a loop for summing up consecutive column values in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, sum, nested-loops

I am trying to produce an loop function to sum up consecutive columns of values of a table and output them into another table

For example, in my original table, we have columns a, b, c, etc, which contain the same number of numeric values.
The resulting table then should be a, a+b, a+b+c, etc up to the last column of the original table

I have a feeling a for loop should be sufficient for this operation however can't get my head around the format and syntax.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stack. the idea here is to give a minimal reproducible example ([mcve]) so that the others can give you answers using your example. If you could give the code of what you have tried so far, it would be appreciated too.

Comment: hi, sorry about that, 
the code I am using at the moment is   
CoEig1 = coEigFrame[,1]
  CoEig2 = coEigFrame[,1]+coEigFrame[,2]
  CoEig3 = coEigFrame[,1]+coEigFrame[,2]+coEigFrame[,3]
  
  dataFrame = cbind(CoEig1, CoEig2, CoEig3)

coEigFrame is a data frame of numeric values
However what I want is a for loop or something along that line to do this function instead o this heavy forced code

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new, here is an example of a very minimal minimal reproducible example?

```
library(data.table)
x = data.table(a=1:3,b=4:6,c=7:9)
for(... now what?
```

And here's a way to do your task:

```
library(data.table)
# make some dummy data
X = data.table(a=1:2,b=3:4,c=5:6)
# make an empty result table
Y = data.table()
# for i = 1 to the number of columns in X
for(i in 1:ncol(X)){
  # colnames(X) is "a" "b" "c".
  # colnames(X)[1:1] is "a", colnames(X)[1:2] is "a" "b", colnames(X)[1:3] is "a" "b" "c"
  # paste0(colnames(X)[1:1],collapse='') is "a",
  # paste0(colnames(X)[1:2],collapse='') is "ab",
  # paste0(colnames(X)[1:3],collapse='') is "abc"
  newcolname = paste0(colnames(X)[1:i],collapse='')
  # Y[,(newcolname):= is data.table syntax to create a new column called newcolname
  # X[,1:i] selects columns 1 to i
  # rowSums calculates the, um, row sums :D
  Y[,(newcolname):=rowSums(X[,1:i])]
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
I will try better for my next query!

This error message comes up, "Error in rowSums(coEigFrame[, 1:i]) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions" 
CoEigFrame is just a data frame I'm using consisting of 3 columns of numeric values, it has no column names, just "1", "2", "3"

Comment: You have to use data.table for this code to work, not data.frame. To convert a data.frame to a data.table, do `setDT(myData)` to convert myData to a data.table in-place. btw, don't do `myData = setDT(myDate)`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need `Reduce` like below

```
cbind(
  df,
  setNames(
    as.data.frame(Reduce(`+`, df, accumulate = TRUE)),
    Reduce(paste0, names(df), accumulate = TRUE)
  )
)
```

such that

```
  a b c a ab abc
1 1 4 7 1  5  12
2 2 5 8 2  7  15
3 3 6 9 3  9  18
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```